# Is this possible with Magento?

Tags: magento, payment

I want to create a **private store** (disable frontend user registration and guest checkout, only enable the option for the admin to add new users).

I want to give the registered user the possibility to purchase items without paying at the checkout. I don't want to add products with the price set to 0.00, because at the end of the month I want to send them the invoice covering all the purchases for that month (and for that, I want the products to have the price).

**It this possible with Magento?**

Please let me know, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'Professional' and 'Enterprise' versions have B2B features to support this.

You can also achieve the same with some free extensions, use [Customer Activation](http://www.magentocommerce.com/extension/489/customer-activation) with [Login only catalog](http://www.magentocommerce.com/extension/490/login-only-catalog).

For the checkout problem disable all payment methods except "Purchase Order". Orders charged this way can be invoiced and cleared at a later date.

Comment: Thanks. I disabled all the payment methods except "Purchase Order". Everything works fine but I get "Purchase Order Number". What is this? Can I disable it? About disabling user registration in the frontend, it is possible?

Comment: I believe the normal business practice is to assign such a number to each of your customers so they can use it for quoting. Instead of purchase order you can also use the "Check/Money Order" payment type which also clears instantly but doesn't require any input, you can change it's name to something more applicable like "Invoice" or "Credit".

Answer (score 1):

FYI, such features are not available by default in Community Edition.
But this is possible via this Magento Extension called **Store Restriction Pro**:
http://www.magepsycho.com/store-restriction-pro.html

Hope this helps.
Thanks